# How to get the date before 180 days?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the exact date before 180 days using Java script. ie: If the selected date is '26-12-2012', then the output is '30-06-2012'(before 180 days).

I've tried with:

```
var ndate      = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
 var day1       = ndate.getDate();
 var month1     = ndate.getMonth();
 var year1      = ndate.getFullYear();
 document.entry.callback.value = day1+"-"+month1+"-"+year1;
```

It works but not exactly. When the selected date is in the month of June,  then the output Month is showed as '0'. Ie: '02-06-2012' then the result is '04-0-2012'.

What would be the better solution for this!

Answer (score 3):

This is quite exact.

In `Date` object month starts with `0`:

> **getMonth**
>
> Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to
>   local time.

So, June should be `5`, whilst `6` is July.

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Yes dude, I knew it but then i store this it in to an DB for future follow up status. We can't save the month as '0'. Any other way to do it!

Comment: well clearly the problem, then, isn't that its retreiving the 180 days. the problem is a 0 based number for which you can simply add 1 to the month. javascript uses a 0 based month system. you have to do the conversion yourself.